# How i can mock Reselect functions with jest?

Tags: jestjs, redux-saga, reselect

I try to test my `saga` and i have some problems with testing `select`.

I want to mock `createSelector` from `reselect`, but i can't do this, because i have this error:

`Cannot read property \'module\' of undefined`

my reselect:

```js
//R - is ramda

export const selectFilters = createSelector(R.path(['notification', 'filters']), (filters) => filters)
```

my saga:

```js
//module gives me error because selectFilters returns undefined

const {module, orderByDate} = yield select(selectors.selectFilters())
```

Comment: You need to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) or at least provide more relevant code. If you're following a tutorial, add a reference to it too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to pass the reference to of the selector the the `select` effect. In your saga, you are actually calling the selector, and then passing the return value. If you do it properly, you don't have to mock the selector.

Modify your code like this to fix the error:

```
const {module, orderByDate} = yield select(selectors.selectFilters)
```

Answer (score 0):

2 ways.

1.

```
jest.mock('bla/bla/selectors', () => ({
  selectFilters: jest.fn(() => anythingToReturn),
}));
```

2. 

```
import {selectFilters} from 'bla/bla/selectors'

jest.mock('bla/bla/selectors')

it('should ...', () => {
   (selectFilters as any).mockReturnValueOnce(anythingToReturn)
})
```